# Adding Regex in XML crashes the application

Tags: php, regex, xml

I am trying to put my regex in a resource XML file.
When my XML file is parsed, it throws an exception and crashes the app.

```
(^(?!\s)(?!.*\s\s)[ A-Za-z0-9'-]{1,35}(?&lt;!\s)$)
```

Am I missing any escape sequences here? Otherwise, what would cause the crash?

Comment: Maybe that is because of the `'`? Try `&apos;`. Doubling the backslashes may also be required (however, that would not cause any crash).

Comment: Got it, I am trying it out

Comment: Can you share the results of the testing?

Comment: Please post the whole XML section with the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your regex inside `<![CDATA[(^(?!\s)(?!.*\s\s)[ A-Za-z0-9'-]{1,35}(?&lt;!\s)$)]]>`

It will make the text inside not be interpreted as xml.